# Prevent user from double clicking in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, submit

I have tried the following two scripts to prevent user from submitting the below form more than one. The submit button is being disabled in both cases, however the form is not being sent (placed a break point and the OnClick method is not being called)

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="BtnSubmit_Click" />
```

Scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        $("#BtnSubmit").click(function () {
        var button = $(this);
        button.prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function () {
            button.prop('disabled', false);
        }, 5000);
    });</script>
```

and

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
$('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Comment: The `OnClick` method probably isn't being called because the specific button is disabled, and the default behavior of submitting a form is to not include any disabled inputs in the payload (so ASP.NET can't know the button was clicked). My one quick idea is to change the `type` of the button to "button" (instead of "submit"), instead of disabling it. That way, it won't submit the form if clicked again at least

Comment: Also, you could try this: http://encosia.com/disable-a-button-control-during-postback/

Comment: @Ian the link actually worked so well. Thank you. Post as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick idea is to change the type of the button to "button" (instead of "submit"), instead of disabling it. That way, it won't submit the form if clicked again at least.

Another other idea comes from here: http://encosia.com/disable-a-button-control-during-postback/ -

The important text from the link:

> The one pitfall that comes with disabling a submit button on the
>   client side is that it will cancel the browser’s submit, and thus the
>   postback. Setting the `UseSubmitBehavior` property to `false` tells .NET
>   to inject the necessary client script to fire the postback anyway,
>   instead of relying on the browser’s form submission behavior.

Following that, your button would look something like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnSubmit" Text="Submit"
  OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting...';" 
  UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
  OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click" />
```

I don't like the inline `OnClientClick`, so you should try taking it out and keeping your jQuery click handler, as well as setting the `UseSubmitBehavior` appropriately. I have a feeling the order of events shouldn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

For the former, you would have to do instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
$("#<%= BtnSubmit.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        var button = $(this);
        button.prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function () {
            button.prop('disabled', false);
        }, 5000);
    });</script>
```

The actual ID is going to be way longer than btnsubmit, unless you have `ClientIDMode="Static"` defined. (something like ct100_contentplaceholder_btnsubmit).  Using the ClientID property from the server locates the proper ID of the control.

Comment: `The submit button is being disabled in both cases, however the form is not being sent`

Comment: Like @Ian said, the button id was not the problem